# Simplify Boolean expression with De Morgan's laws

Tags: boolean-expression, demorgans-law

I need to simplify this Boolean expression with [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

```
¬c xor (¬b ∨ c)
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Come on. Stackoverflow isn't a place where people will do homework for you. What have you tried? What do you not understand/DO understand about de morgan's law?

Comment: Do your homework on your own. It's super-easy...

Comment: I don't understand nothing from de morgan's laws, that is the reason that I ask foe help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(accidentally made two accounts, so just responding with this one)

Ive found the best way to visualize a logic formula you do not understand is to make a table for it.

In the case of XOR, it represents One variable or another, but not both. So, lets make a table for A XOR B

A | B | Result

T | T | F     *1
T | F | T     *2
F | T | T     *3
F | F | F     *4

To generate the smallest possible result from the above table we can first take the most complex result that takes into account each option. Converting each line into a logical statement is fairly easy.

First, throw out anything that results in a False, Then take those that result in true, and convert them into a logical statement separated by 'OR's. In this case, 1 and 4 are false, and 2 and 3 are true. This means we only need to create logical statements for 2 and 3. I think how to do so would be best explained by example

Lets say X, Y, and Z are our variables, and the table gave us the following rows as true:
T | T | F    -   X & Y & ¬Z
F | T | F    -  ¬X & Y & ¬Z
F | F | F    -  ¬X & ¬Y & ¬Z

then to complete, we simply 'OR' them together

(X & Y & ¬Z) V (¬X & Y & ¬Z) V (¬X & ¬Y & ¬Z)

as you can see, where the variable is true, you put the variable directly in, and where it is false, you put a '¬' before the variable. The statement above basically says...

(True when X=T,Y=T,Z=F: False otherwise) OR (True when X=F,Y=T,Z=F: False otherwise) OR (True when X=F,Y=F,Z=F: False otherwise)

So finally bringing it back to our XOR the table rows are...

*2  A & ¬B
*3 ¬A & B

and are combined to be...

(A & ¬B) V (¬A & B)

So, now that you have an explanation of what to do with xor, you can apply this example to your problem, and come up with a logical statement you can use De Morgan's laws on to simplify.

Comment: First I try to solve this with de Morgan's laws. For the first time I work with this laws, and I don't know if my result is true?

c' xor (b' + c)

And I don't know how to continue with solving the expression

Comment: De Morgan's Laws are ultimately just passing a negative into a Parenthesis. They are helpful in rearranging equations so that you can cancel out useless Logic (such as: A & B & A is the same as A & B, and ¬A & A is always False).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgans_laws

Comment: I try this  c' xor (b' + c) , and I don't know how to continue with expression,

Comment: I'm sorry but your going to have to go see someone in person about this and explain it to you step by step, or you probably wont understand it.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to split up xor into its basic form.

XOR represents A or B where A != B. If you can do that you should have more luck using demorgans on the whole equation

Comment: Could you help me with some tutorial where is explain how to do this?